# How to include .css file in smarty template file?

Tags: html, css, smarty

Hello  I am a newbie in php, html, css, and smarty.  How to insert/include a css file to a html file in smarty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer from @Nambi Narayanan looks very wrong and badly implemented. I advise you to use the following block:

```
{block name=head}
    <link href="/css/mypage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
{/block}
```

or you can just include the link tag straight in the page without Smarty:

```
<link href="/css/mypage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```